# How to go about clearing a 2d Array of Strings when a user wins. (Connect Four)

Tags: java, arrays

For my intro to Programming class, we are creating a 2 player Connect Four game, where it alternates between users, checks for a winner after every move, displays the winner, then asks the players if they'd like to play another game or not. The display is through the console. The algorithms for my win check's have proven decent, but my problem lies in resetting the 2-D String array I made to hold the players moves, after a winner has been chosen. I am not quite sure how to do that with the the array I have created.

Here is what I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ConnectFourGame {

    public static String [] [] createPattern() {

        String [] [] board = new String [8][27];

        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {

                if (j == 3 || j == 7 || j == 11 || j == 15 || j == 19 ||  
                J == 23) board[i][j] = "|";

                else board [i][j] = " ";

                if (i == 6) board[i][j] = "-";

                if (i == 7 && j == 1) board [i][j] = "1";
                if (i == 7 && j == 5) board [i][j] = "2";
                if (i == 7 && j == 9) board [i][j] = "3";
                if (i == 7 && j == 13) board [i][j] = "4";
                if (i == 7 && j == 17) board [i][j] = "5";
                if (i == 7 && j == 21) board [i][j] = "6";
                if (i == 7 && j == 25) board [i][j] = "7";
            }
        }
        return board;
}

public static void printPattern(String[][] board) {

    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(board[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}


public static void firstRowRed(String[][] board) {

    System.out.println("Player 1: Your turn! (Select a column, 1-7)");
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    int num;

    num = input.nextInt();
    int k = (2*((2*num)-1)-1); 


    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {

        if (board[i][k] == " ") {

            board[i][k] = "R";
            break;
        }
    }

}

public static void firstRowYellow(String[][] board) {

    System.out.println(" Player 2: Your turn! (select a column, 1-7)");
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    int num;
    num = input.nextInt();
    int k = (2*((2*num)-1)-1);

    for (int i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {

        if (board[i][k] == " ") {

            board[i][k] = "Y";
            break;
        }
    }
} 

public static String checkWinner (String [][] board) {

    // Horizontal Line check
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 15; j += 4) {

            if ((board[i][j+1] != " ")  
                && (board[i][j + 5] != " ")
                && (board[i][j + 9] != " ")
                && (board[i][j + 13] != " ")
                && ((board[i][j + 1] == board [i][j + 5])
                && (board[i][j + 5] == board [i][j + 9])
                && (board[i][j + 9] == board [i][j + 13])))


                return board[i][j+1];

            }
        }
        // Vertical line win check  
        for (int i = 1; i < 27; i += 4) {

            for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) {

                if ((board[j][i] != " ")
                && (board[j + 1][i] != " ")
                && (board[j + 2][i] != " ")
                && (board[j + 3][i] != " ")
                && (board[j][i] == board[j + 1][i])
                && (board[j + 1][i] == board[j + 2][i])
                && (board[j + 2][i] == board[j + 3][i]))

                return board[j][i];
            }   
    }

        // Top Left to bottom right diagonal win check   
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            for (int j = 1; j < 13 ; j +=4) {

                if ((board[i][j] != " ")
                && (board[i + 1][j + 4] != " ")
                && (board[i + 2][j + 8] != " ")
                && (board[i + 3][j + 12] != " ")
                && ((board[i][j] == board[i + 1][j + 4])
                && (board[i + 1][j + 4] == board[i + 2][j + 8])
                && (board[i + 2][j + 8] == board[i + 3][j + 12])))

                return board[i][j];
            }
        }

        // Top right to bottom left win check
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {


            for (int j = 1; j < 27; j += 4) {

                if ((board[i][j] != " ")
                && (board[i + 1][j - 4] != " ")
                && (board[i + 2][j - 8] != " ")
                && (board[i + 3][j - 12] != " ")
                && ((board[i][j] == board[i + 1][j - 4])
                && (board[i + 1][j - 4] == board [i + 2][j - 8])
                && (board[i + 2][j - 8] == board [i + 3][j - 12])))

                return board[i][j];
            }
        }

        return null;
}


public static void main (String[] args) {

    String [][] board = createPattern();

    boolean loop = true;
    int count = 0;
    printPattern(board);


    int quit;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    while(loop) {

        if ( count % 2 == 0) firstRowRed(board);
        else firstRowYellow(board);
        count++;
        printPattern(board);

        if(checkWinner(board) != null) {
            if (checkWinner(board) == "R")
                System.out.println("Player 1 wins!");
            else if (checkWinner(board) == "Y")
                System.out.println("Player 2 wins!");
            if(checkWinner(board) == "R" || checkWinner(board) == "Y"){
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Enter -1 to end game, or enter 0 to 
                                        continue");
                quit = input.nextInt();

                if(quit == -1)
                    loop = false;

                if(quit == 0)
                    continue;
```

Answer (score 0):

just re-create the board between games, not just when the program starts:

```
board = createPattern();
```

You could re-use the same matrix, or allocate a new one each game.

Comment: That makes too much sense. Thank you! Sometimes you stare at something for so long you just miss it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your asking how to set your string to an empty string or not but if so your code would be something like this to reset your string to empty:

c#: create string array with empty value

```
string[][] str = new string[][] { };
```

That is if you want to set it to a empty string value. You could also just create a new board as suggested below and that's likely the best practice. Another option would be creating a "reset" game function or something. I hope that helps.

Comment: At first thats what I though I needed to do, but that would set the grid I created to empy. So like Malt said about, i just reused the same matrix. Thank you though!

Comment: @mholmes the question is about Java. Why C#?

Comment: Pretty similar syntax and the concept of setting an array to empty string is similar. So I hope it was not too confusing and I hope they found it helpful. And C# / VB our the languages I know. so I again I hope I did not confuse anyone.